# How to publish a rpm package to YUM

Tags: centos, rpm, yum

I have created a rpm package, and I need to publish it to YUM so that users can directly do yum install softwareName to install the application. I searched on google but can't find many resources. I'm new to this thing so I don't really know what I want to do is possible. I've tried to create a local yum repository for the application, but it seems work only for the local machine. Can anyone help please? Thank you.

Comment: If your goal is just make this rpm installable by other users, you just can share it via GoogleDrive / DropBox / Web server / FTP server etc. Users can download it, verify signatures and install it via `$ sudo yum localinstall /path/to/your.rpm`. Unfortunately I also don't know how to place your rpm into one of public RPM repositories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you've YUM installed on a Linux box.

You need to create a YUM repository that contains your RPM. For example,

```
./mydir/Packages/my.rpm
```

Use `createrepo` to create repository for that directory.

```
createrepo ./mydir
```

Above would create a `repodata` directory in `./mydir`

Then tell YUM where that repository is by creating a repo file in `/etc/yum.repos.d/my.repo`. Contents of `my.repo` can be something like this:

```
[my_repo]
name=My YUM REPO
baseurl=file:///path/to/mydir
enabled=1
```

Then do, `yum --enablerepo=* clean all`. This should regenerate metadata for yum.

Finally,

```
`yum --enablerepo=* install my`
```

Above, `my` refers to `my.rpm`

In order to access this from other machines on the network, you need a web access,

Install `http`. Place your repository somewhere in, `/var/www/html/repos/mydir/Packages/my.rpm`

Then follow other steps and edit `my.repo` file to include `hostname` of the machine in the `baseurl` attribute :

```
 baseurl=http://myrepository.com/mydir
```

Comment: Thank you! But I got an error like this:  `failure: repodata/repomd.xml from c7-media: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
file:///media/CentOS/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#37 - "Couldn't open file /media/CentOS/repodata/repomd.xml"
file:///media/cdrom/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#37 - "Couldn't open file /media/cdrom/repodata/repomd.xml"
file:///media/cdrecorder/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#37 - "Couldn't open file /media/cdrecorder/repodata/repomd.xml"`   I'm testing this on Docker because I use Mac. Is it the reason why I got the error? Thank you!

Comment: You can disable any repo during runtime by executing, `yum --enablerepo=* --disablerepo=c7-media install my`. You can also use just your own repo, `yum --enablerepo=my_repo install my`. You can also disable a repo inside `/etc/yum.repos.d/name.repo` and mark `enabled=0`

Comment: Just small correction - you should use `createrepo_c` when possible. It runs much much faster.

Comment: @iamauser so if I have a web access, how do other machines install package my? Do they still need to do the things listed above, such as having the rpm package and creating the repo? Thank you so much!

Comment: Also, when I try to install http, it says `No package http available.` How do I resolve this issue? Thank you for your help! I really appreciate this.